# Can you make an entire webpage fixed with only one container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

Can't seem to find the answer to my question.

Right now I am learning how to use bootstrap, and I read it needs a container to wrap the sites elements. I want the entire webpage to be in a fixed position, not full width. But I don't understand if I can just use one div class="container" for the whole page, or if it has to be for every section such as the navigation bar, header, etc..?

I am not sure if I have explained myself correctly. If you have any questions please ask and I will try to explain it better.

**EDIT**

Below Jackson said "You can use one container div if you like but then all of your page will be contained within that space. It depends on your intention"

*That is what I would like to do, but i don't know where to put the container tag to achieve that.*

I am sorry for not being clear. I also don't have any code to show because I haven't tried to make it yet considering how confused I am about this.

Comment: The container wrapper allows the site to be centered on the screen. What do you mean you want the webpage to be in a fixed position?

Comment: You probably should provide some code with a more specific question.

Comment: @Jackson I guess what I really am asking is where should I put the container tag in my html?

Comment: You can use one container div if you like but then all of your page will be contained within that space. It depends on your intention - for example - maybe you want to make the header to span the full width of the screen (like [this page](http://tutorialzine.com/) )

Comment: @Jackson I do want it to be all contained within that space, though I do like how that webpage looks. So how would I be able to achieve both looks?

Comment: @zavly To achieve that look then you would just put the container below where you put your header. That way the header is not contained within the container and can span full-width of the page. Then everything inside the container will (obviously) stay contained within the container.

Comment: What do you mean 'fixed position'? That's typically not very responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned, use the [.container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) class for fixed layout.  There are multiple right answers.  Your container can be the first div inside your body tags.  Or you can use the container inside of nav and other divs like so.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- head stuff -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- navbar stuff -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- jumbotron stuff -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- content stuff -->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to check out this [Bootstrap Starter Template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I know what you're talking about, you want something like this:

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav">This would be where your header/nav links go</div>
<div class="container">
    Everything else on your page that you want "contained" would go inside this container
</div>
```

In the above example, the header/navigation would span full-width of the page and everything inside the container would stay within the space of the container.

Answer (score 0):

The [container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) has two main purposes:

- Make your content fixed-width (can use the fluid container if you want full width)
- House grid components (the `.row`s and `.col-...`s)

When you use `.row`, it sets a negative left and right margin to account for the gutter between columns. A container creates left and right padding to counter this negative margin on the rows. Without the container, your rows would extend outside of the page and cause horizontal-scrolling (probably not desirable).

So the proper way to use containers would be to wrap your grid components in them:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As far as using multiple containers goes, it depends on the situation. Bootstrap uses containers in some of its other components such as [navbars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default). But generally, you should just need one container for the majority of the page as you can have multiple rows in the same container. The main reason for having a new one might be to switch between a fluid container and fixed-width container.